# How to show canvas on tapping on the image

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have defined datatemplate in app.xaml
I have there an image
And in my custom page I have a canvas
How can I show this canvas on tapping on the image?
Here is my datatemplate in app.xaml

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FlightInfoDataTemplate">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="420">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <!-- here are controls, which are not necessary now-->
                    <Image Tag="{Binding ID}" Source="/Images/bel_icon_2.png" Width="20" Height="20" Visibility="{Binding Path=Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                <!--***********-->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Here is my canvas which is defined in MainPage.xaml

```
<Canvas x:Name="AddReminderDialog" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Height="280" Width="260"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Margin="110,178,110,238" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <TextBlock Foreground="Yellow" Text="Напомнить" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="78" Canvas.Top="28" />
            <Button Name="btn1HourBef" BorderThickness="0" Background="Black" Content="За час" Width="260" FontSize="15" Height="60" Margin="0,70,0,0"/>
            <Button Name="btn30MinBef" BorderThickness="0" Background="Black" Content="За 30 минут" Width="260" FontSize="15" Height="60" Margin="0,130,0,0"/>
            <Button Name="btn10MinBef" BorderThickness="0" Background="Black" Content="По прилету/вылету" Width="260" FontSize="15" Height="60" Margin="0,190,0,0"/>
        </Canvas>
```

How can I make it visible on tapping on the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit - canvas was meant to be used as a notification, and preferably reusable on several pages:**

Per comments, it became clear the intention of the canvas was to provide a notification message. Something suitable for the concept of a dismissible popup. There already is a System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup class in the framework.

Example:
In App.xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FlightInfoDataTemplate">
...
<Image Tag="{Binding ID}" Source="/Images/bel_icon_2.png" Width="20" Height="20" Visibility="{Binding Path=Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToVisibilityConverter}}" Tap="Image_Tap"/>
...
</DataTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="AddReminderDialog">
    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Height="280" Width="260" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="WhiteSmoke" Margin="110,178,110,238">
        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="78" Canvas.Top="28" />
        <Button Name="btn1HourBef" BorderThickness="0" Background="Black" Content="За час" Width="260" FontSize="15" Height="60" Margin="0,70,0,0"/>
        <Button Name="btn30MinBef" BorderThickness="0" Background="Black" Content="За 30 минут" Width="260" FontSize="15" Height="60" Margin="0,130,0,0"/>
        <Button Name="btn10MinBef" BorderThickness="0" Background="Black" Content="По прилету/вылету" Width="260" FontSize="15" Height="60" Margin="0,190,0,0"/>
    </Canvas>
</ControlTemplate>
```

In App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private Popup popup = new Popup();
...

private void Image_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var image = sender as Image;
    var modelItem = image.DataContext;

    const double width = 200;
    const double height = 100;

    var content = new ContentControl(){Width = width, Height = height, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple)};
    content.Template = (ControlTemplate) Resources["AddReminderDialog"];
    content.DataContext = modelItem; // you should define bindings in the ControlTemplate.

    popup.Child = content;
    popup.Height = height;
    popup.Width = width;
    popup.VerticalOffset = Application.Current.RootVisual.RenderSize.Height / 2 - height / 2;
    popup.HorizontalOffset = Application.Current.RootVisual.RenderSize.Width / 2 - width / 2;
    popup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: But my AddReminderDialog is defined on the MainPage.xaml. And datatemplate is on the App.xaml, in resources

Comment: @Umriyaev I'm sorry, I misread the question. I'll update with correct info.

Comment: I'd define that datatemplate in mainpage.xaml, but that template is used in several pages, thus, I thought it would be better to define it in application resources. I also wanted to define canvas in application resources, but when you change visibility of popup to visible, it will become visible only on that page where it's defined. That's why I defined canvas in the mainpage and other pages, where datatemplate is used.

Comment: The main purpose of my application is to show information about flights. Currently I'm showing information about local and global flights in separate pages. Besides that, I also have categories of arrivals and departures. All in all, I have 4 pages, showing info about flights: local arrivals, local departures, global arrivals and global departures. That's why I decided to make common datatemplate in application resources. Now, I want to add notification feature. That's why I need popup.

Comment: @Umriyaev I see. Your question did not mention anything about any popup. In that case you can use the Popup class. I can provide an example.

Comment: How can I hide popup on navigating from the page, where it's activated? When I'm leaving the page popup is remaining active

Comment: How can I get button, which is defined in the content template of the popup, in code behind? I added button to cancel notification, and it's invisible by default, I want to make it visible if user taps the image second time. But I can't get the button, which I added to the controlTemplate, which was defined by you, in the code-behind